# Why next.js duplicates styles?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a next.js project. For styling I am using tailwind, scss modules and postcss. I have no overridden webpack configurations.

In development mode next.js injects styles in  tags as expected, but in production it injects similar styles as *.css chunks and  tag at the same time.

[Next.js style duplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2EHz.png)

Comment: Hey, i'm just curious are you not using: `@tailwind base; @tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;` twice right?

Comment: @AhmadShiddiq I have `@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';` in several scss files because I need to use @layer utilities inside them

Comment: @AhmadShiddiq Just removed it but no effect.

Comment: Probably same situation: [github issue 1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19055) and [github issue 2](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/11901#issuecomment-614644961)

Comment: @Enfield li I think not. I haven't similar components imported in _app.js and page both

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Next.js' experimental `optimizeCss` with Tailwind or other CSS frameworks? It might be duplicating style as it injects inline CSS.

Comment: Yes, that was an issue